# Show that the iterations $x_{n+1}=f(x_{n})$ diverges to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $f:ℝ→ℝ$ be a continuous and strictly increasing function. Assuming that $f$ has no fixed point.

Show that the iterations $$x_{n+1}=f(x_{n})$$ diverges to $+∞$ or $-∞$. I have no idea to start.

Comment: It is me or f(x) = x-1 is a counter example ?

Comment: @hivert It is a counterexample. In that case the iterations will diverge to $-\infty$, not $\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Show that the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is strictly monotone. It is increasing if $x_1=f(x_0)>x_0$ and decreasing otherwise ($f(x_0)\not=x_0$ by hypothesis). Hence the limit of this sequence exists  (in the extended reals).

What happens if this limit is finite, say $L$? Is there any relation between $F(L)$ and $L$?

Note that the conclusion should be that $f(x)$ diverges to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ (not just $+\infty$, see hivert's counterexample).

Comment: $(x_n)$ need not be increasing, but it is still true that it is strictly monotone.

Comment: You are right, Thanks!

Comment: Do we need the hypothesis that $f$ is differentiable? It seems to me that continuity suffices.

Comment: Right. Continuity suffices.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that ($x_n$) does not diverge to infinity then, from the definition of the limit there is A>0 such that for each integer k you can fine another integer $n_k$ which satisfy $|x_{n_k}|<A$.

Moving this iteration step by step you can exact a bounded subsequence of $x_{n}$ which contains another converging subsequence due to Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem. then check if the limit obtained is a fixed point of $f$.